# How do I reduce spacing between 2 segments of a line in a multiple alignment environment?

Tags: align, indexing, alignment, mhchem, alignat

Currently, there is a large gap between the 2 segments of a line, causing its index to be pushed to the following line. How can I prevent this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
Overall formation of ethane thingy: \ce{2 C(s) + 3 H2(g) -> C2H6(g)} \\
\begin{alignat}{2}
\ce{2C(s) + 2O2(g) &-> 2CO2(g)} &\Delta H &=  -786 kJ\\
\ce{3H2(g) + 3/2 O2(g) &-> H2O(l)} &\Delta H &= -858 kJ\\
\ce{2 CO2(g) + 3 H2O(l) &-> C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2 (g)} &\Delta H &= 1560 kJ\\
\nonumber \ce{2 C(s) + 3 H2(g) + 7/2 O2(g) &-> C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2(g)} &\indent \Delta H &= -786-858+1560\\ 
\nonumber & &&= -84 kJ \\
\nonumber &&\therefore \Delta H_{f(C_2H6)}^0 &= -84kJ 
\end{alignat}{2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Other typography issues: Write phyical units (kJ) upright and separated by a space. `H_{f(C_2H6)}^0` is wrong on several levels: subscript f should be upright, subscript formula should be upright (use `\ce`), superscript is not a 0, but `\circ`. IUPAC recommendation (Green Book) is to write `\Delta_{\mathrm{f}}H^\circ (\ce{C2H6})`. Lastly, are you sure about your calculation? Unit of standard enthalpy is not kJ.

Answer (score 4):

Here, I use `\mathllap` on the last line.  But as you can see, there is still one remaining margin issue that you need to consider.

Also, the `\end{alignat}` does not take an argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
Overall formation of ethane thingy: \ce{2 C(s) + 3 H2(g) -> C2H6(g)} \\
\begin{alignat}{2}
\ce{2C(s) + 2O2(g) &-> 2CO2(g)} &\Delta H &=  -786 kJ\\
\ce{3H2(g) + 3/2 O2(g) &-> H2O(l)} &\Delta H &= -858 kJ\\
\ce{2 CO2(g) + 3 H2O(l) &-> C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2 (g)} &\Delta H &= 1560 kJ\\
\nonumber \ce{2 C(s) + 3 H2(g) + 7/2 O2(g) &-> C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2(g)} &\indent \Delta H &= -786-858+1560\\ 
\nonumber & &&= -84 kJ \\
\nonumber &&\mathllap{\therefore \Delta H_{f(C_2H6)}^0} &= -84kJ 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could try to break up the remaining long line, but there may be other approaches, too...

I also made your `kJ` units upright, though, as marmot points out, the `siunitx` package is tailor made for applying units to quantities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
Overall formation of ethane thingy: \ce{2 C(s) + 3 H2(g) -> C2H6(g)} \\
\begin{alignat}{2}
\ce{2C(s) + 2O2(g) &-> 2CO2(g)} &\Delta H &=  -786 \mathrm{\,kJ}\\
\ce{3H2(g) + 3/2 O2(g) &-> H2O(l)} &\Delta H &= -858 \mathrm{\,kJ}\\
\ce{2 CO2(g) + 3 H2O(l) &-> C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2 (g)} &\Delta H &= 1560 \mathrm{\,kJ}\\
\nonumber \ce{2 C(s) + 3 H2(g) + 7/2 O2(g) &-> C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2(g)} &\indent \Delta H &= -786-858\\\nonumber&&&\phantom{{}={}}+1560\\ 
\nonumber & &&= -84 \mathrm{\,kJ} \\
\nonumber &&\mathllap{\therefore \Delta H_{f(C_2H6)}^0} &= -84\mathrm{\,kJ} 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need another `\nonumber` in the second iteration; the last equation isn't numbered in the original.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a nice opportunity to advertize `siunitx` for `kJ`?

Comment: Thank you, @barbarabeeton

Comment: Regarding `H_{f(C_2H6)}^0` part: **a.** According to IUPAC, [standard state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_state#Typesetting) should be denoted with either a superscript circle (`^\circ`) or a superscript Plimsoll symbol (`^⦵` + xelatex compiler), not a zero; **b.** subscript `f` ("**f**ormation") should be upright, e.g. `\mathrm{f}`; **c.** It would be nice to fix typesetting for ethane (proper indices and upright font), e.g. with `\ce{C2H6}`. I also agree with @marmot that using `siunitx` would make the answer look more professional.

Answer (score 2):

Use of fullpage style (must be the shortest CTAN manual that nobody reads :-)
you could just add in preamble

\usepackage{fullpage}

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
Overall formation of ethane thingy: \ce{2 C(s) + 3 H2(g) -> C2H6(g)} \\
\begin{alignat}{2}
\ce{2C(s) + 2O2(g) &-> 2CO2(g)} &\Delta H &=  -786 kJ\\
\ce{3H2(g) + 3/2 O2(g) &-> H2O(l)} &\Delta H &= -858 kJ\\
\ce{2 CO2(g) + 3 H2O(l) &-> C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2 (g)} &\Delta H &= 1560 kJ\\
\nonumber \ce{2 C(s) + 3 H2(g) + 7/2 O2(g) &-> C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2(g)} &\indent \Delta H &= -786-858+1560\\ 
\nonumber & &&= -84 kJ \\
\nonumber &&\therefore \Delta H_{f(C_2H6)}^0 &= -84kJ 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does steal a bit of the left margin, if that is not acceptable I think you would need to wrap the final term over two lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
Overall formation of ethane thingy: \ce{2 C(s) + 3 H2(g) -> C2H6(g)}%Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) \\
\begin{alignat}{2}
\ce{2C(s) + 2O2(g) &-> 2CO2(g)} &\Delta H &=  -786 kJ\\
\ce{3H2(g) + 3/2 O2(g) &-> H2O(l)} &\Delta H &= -858 kJ\\
\ce{2 CO2(g) + 3 H2O(l) &-> C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2 (g)} &\Delta H &= 1560 kJ\\
\nonumber\hspace*{-250pt}\ce{2 C(s) + 3 H2(g) + 7/2 O2(g) &-> C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2(g)} &\Delta H &= -786-858+1560\\ 
\nonumber & &&= -84 kJ \\
\nonumber &\therefore& \Delta H_{f(C_2H6)}^0  &= -84kJ 
\end{alignat}{2}
\end{document}
```

Note I moved the `\therefore` back a bit so it's not so cramped (and so the display is a bit narrower and requires less overhang).  Also never use `\\` before a display.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a little bit on what you meant when you said "never use \\ before a display"? Was there an extra \\ in my document where there shouldn't have been one?

Comment: @DavidLu  yes latex must have screamed badness 10000 at you:-) (that is it's _maximum_ level in its assessment of the poor quality of the output), the `\\ ` before `\begin{alignat}` on the first line after `C2H6(g)}` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you have space constraints, you can use more lines:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\move}[2]{\hspace{#1}\makebox[0pt][r]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

Overall formation of ethane thingy: \ce{2 C(s) + 3 H2(g) -> C2H6(g)}, in units~\si{\kilo\joule}
\begin{align}
\ce{2C(s) + 2O2(g) &-> 2CO2(g)} \\
  \nonumber &\move{6em}{\Delta H} = -786 \\
\ce{3H2(g) + 3/2 O2(g) &-> H2O(l)} \\
  \nonumber & \move{6em}{\Delta H} = -858 \\
\ce{2 CO2(g) + 3 H2O(l) &-> C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2 (g)} \\
  \nonumber & \move{6em}{\Delta H} = 1560 \\
\ce{2 C(s) + 3 H2(g) + 7/2 O2(g) &-> C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2(g)} \\
  \nonumber & \move{6em}{\Delta H} = -786-858+1560\\ 
  \nonumber & \move{6em}{} = -84 \\
  \nonumber & \move{6em}{\therefore \Delta H_{f(\ce{C_2H6})}^0} = \SI{-84}{\kilo\joule}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]